# Visual Studio: Conditional break point causes program to slow down

Tags: c#, debugging, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-debugging

I have a conditional break point in a .NET 6 ASP.NET API, which causes the program to slow down immensely. How do I use conditional break points without causing such an impact on performance?

Once I disable the conditional break point it completes and returns a response fairly quickly within a few seconds, if I put a regular break point without conditions to check it just hits the break point quickly like it should. This is specifically the conditional break point that has this issue, it makes me wait for more than 10 minutes before the break point is hit.

A piece of the code:

```cs
List<EntityModel> _data;

public EntityFieldModel ResolveSingle(Field mergeField, EntityModel entity = null)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mergeField.FilterField) && 
    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(mergeField.FilterValue))
        foreach (EntityModel entityModel in _data)
            foreach (EntityFieldModel fieldProperty in entityModel.FieldProperties)

                // The break point is on the if-statement below

                if (
                    entityModel.DatasetId == mergeField.DataSet &&
                    fieldProperty.FieldName == mergeField.FilterField &&
                    fieldProperty.GetFormattedValue(string.Empty) == mergeField.FilterValue
                )
                {
                    entity = entityModel;
                    break;
                }
   ...
}
```

Break point condition:

```
mergeField.FilterValue == "Lorem Ipsum" &&
entityModel.DatasetId == mergeField.DataSet &&
fieldProperty.Value.GetType() == typeof(EntityReference)
```

Is this a common issue with conditional break points? How do I fix this?

Comment: What's unclear about this question?

Comment: Conditional breakpoints slow down debugging immensely (and debugging itself also slows down things). Your in a loop with your conditional how often does the breakpoint gets hit? If _data contains a 6 count number of items then multiplied with the fieldcount yeah that slow down should hurt.

Comment: @Ralf I was trying to write an answer in that direction, but the question was closed before I could finish typing.

Comment: This happens when the break condition is inside inner loops and is executed a great number of time. A work around is to insert in your code at breakpoint location an "if (condition) then entity = entity" and to put the break point after the "then".

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I'm going to try to write a workaround with some extra if-statements.

Comment: The question has been reopenend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's expected. A conditional breakpoint will cause the program to interrupt, switch to the debugger and then evaluate the expression by the debugger. So behind the scenes, a conditional breakpoint requires a lot of communication between the debugger and the application under test. This is expensive. Therefore placing a conditional breakpoint on a line that is executed many times will have a significant performance impact. If you need to analyze a particular problem in a piece of code that's executed many times, it's often faster to introduce the condition into the code and rebuild, like this:

```cs
if (mergeField.FilterValue == "Lorem Ipsum" &&
entityModel.DatasetId == mergeField.DataSet &&
fieldProperty.Value.GetType() == typeof(EntityReference))
{
    int a = 0; // place breakpoint here
}
```